# A list and a figure side by side

Tags: floats, lists

In several documents I have to put side by side a list and a figure.

I use two minipages environments for that, but as the list is too
long, I need to divide it and continue outside the `minipage`
environment (with continuous numbering, hence the utilization of key
series of the `enumitem` package). But, as we may see, the separation
between the first item in the `enumerate` environment outside the `minipage`
and the last item inside the `minipage` is different from the separation
between any other itens.

So, my question is: Is there any way of assure equal separation
between all the itens?

Naturally, I appreciate any hint on a different and better way of doing
this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=.3cm,label=(\alph*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Algum texto com referencia a uma figura.

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
 Uma lista.
\begin{enumerate}[series=exercicio]
 \item primeiro item
 \item segundo item
 \item terceiro item
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t][2cm][c]{0.35\linewidth}
 \centering
 \rule{50pt}{50pt}
\end{minipage}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=exercicio]
 \item quarto item com bastante texto. mais texto e mais texto e mais
  texto
 \item quinto item
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could simply overlay the image and use `\rightskip`.  Alas, `\hangindent` doesn't seem to work with item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*,label=\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=*,itemsep=.3cm,label=(\alph*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Algum texto com referencia a uma figura.

Uma lista.\hfill\llap{\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
\begin{minipage}[t][2cm][c]{0.3\textwidth}% \linewidth is constantly changing here
 \centering
 \rule{50pt}{50pt}
\end{minipage}}}
\begin{enumerate}[series=exercicio]
 \par\rightskip=0.3\textwidth
 \item primeiro item.  Just to demonstrate the effect of \verb$\rightskip$ I am going to add more text here.
 \item segundo item.
 \par\rightskip=0pt
 \item terceiro item.
 \item quarto item com bastante texto. mais texto e mais texto e mais
  texto
 \item quinto item
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: overlay]

Answer (score 3):

Use the package `wrapfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
     \rule{50pt}{50pt}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}

Algúm texto que não é parte de uma lista.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Algum texto com referencia a uma figura.

 Uma lista.
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item primeiro item
   \item segundo item
   \item terceiro item
   \item quarto item com bastante texto. mais texto e mais texto e mais texto
   \item quinto item
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

The [`wrapfig` documentation](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) starts with this caution:

> You must not specify a `wrapfigure` in any type of list environment or immediately before or immediately after one. It is OK to follow a list if there is a blank line (`\par`) in between.

That's why I've added a line of text before the list.

I guess you can play a little so the figure actually appears besides your lists, but the lists cannot be the first or only things wrapping around the figure.

Answer (score 1):

The way text/boxes are laid out is to use a minimum spacing of `\baselineskip` between two consecutive baselines, or `\lineskip` between the lower and upper boundaries of two boxes (whichever is larger).

One way to achieve a relatively constant spacing is to place the baseline for the first minipage at the bottom and the baseline of the second minipage at the top.

Another way is to start and end every minipage with a \strut.

In the case of enumitem, adding `\strut` or `\null` produces way too much space between the two minipages.  Instead you just need to add about 12pt of space between the default minipages (less if you add a `\strut` to the last `\item`).  I'm not sure precisely how enumitem comes up with this 12pt, but this is my best guess.

It should be noted that text inside a minipage is not stretched or squeezed in order to fit the bottom of the page.  You will also need to use `\raggedbottom` or throw in a `\vfil` somewhere, or put both minipages inside a common `\vbox`.

Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[series=test1]
\item One
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=test1]
\item Three
\item Four
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\switchcolumn

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[series=test2]
\item One
\item Two\strut
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\vskip\partopsep\vskip\itemsep\vskip\parsep\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=test2]
\item Three
\item Four
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\bigskip
\switchcolumn*

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
We need at least two lines here in order for this to work, so I hope that this is enough.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
We need at least two lines here in order for this to work, so I hope that this is enough.
\end{minipage}
\switchcolumn

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
We need at least two lines here in order for this to work, so I hope that this is enough.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}
We need at least two lines here in order for this to work, so I hope that this is enough.
\end{minipage}
\bigskip
\switchcolumn*

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
We need at least two lines here in order for this to work, so I hope that this is enough.
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
We need at least two lines here in order for this to work, so I hope that this is enough.
\end{minipage}
\switchcolumn

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\strut
We need at least two lines here in order for this to work, so I hope that this is enough.
\strut
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\strut
We need at least two lines here in order for this to work, so I hope that this is enough.
\strut
\end{minipage}
\bigskip
\switchcolumn*


\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: minipage spacing]