# Different enumerated lists align at the right. How to make them not to?

Tags: lists, align, minipage

I'm trying to make a kind of a dictionary entry (Sample of my code below, sorry for the cyrillic). Here, the first section contains a list of 5 meanings of the word 'чай', tea. As you can see, I added two illustrations using \minipage. But due to this, any other itemized or enumerated list (section n.2) aligns with the list of these meanings, which leaves 3 cm of blank space at the right margin. Is there any way to make them appear as they should?

```
\section{Толкование-Meaning}
    Meanings:  
    \begin{enumerate}  
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}  
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}  
    \vspace{-15pt}  
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Camellia-sinensis-520x390.jpg}  
    {\footnotesize \caption{чай [1]}}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{leaves.jpg}
    {\footnotesize \caption{чай [2]}}  
    \end{wrapfigure   
        \item Культивируемое вечнозеленое растение, высушенные и особо обработанные листья которого при заварке дают ароматный тонизирующий напиток. \textit{Плантации чая. Сбор чая.}   
        \item Высушенные, измельченные и специально обработанные листья такого растения. \textit{Китайский, индийский, грузинский, русский ч. Байховый (рассыпной) и прессованный ч. Черный, зеленый ч. Заварить ч.}  
        \item Напиток, настоянный на таких листьях. \textit{Крепкий, жидкий ч. Стакан чаю. Пригласить на чашку чая (в гости). Ч. пить - не дрова рубить (поcл.).}  
        \item Настой из заваренных сушеных листьев или плодов какого-н. растения, ягод. \textit{Липовый ч. (настой на цветках липы). Малиновый ч. (настой на сушеной малине). Морковный ч. Брусничный ч.}  
        \item То же, что чаепитие. \textit{Вечерний ч. За чаем. Позвать к чаю.}
    \end{minipage}  
    \end{enumerate}  
    \section{Список литературы-References}  
    \begin{enumerate}  
    \item Жгучий глагол: Словарь народной фразеологии. — Зеленый век. В. Кузмич. 2000.   
    \item Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона  
    \item Грамматический словарь русского языка А. А. Зализняка  
    \end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a *full compilable* code?

Comment: Generally speaking, wrapfigure and lists (enumerate) are not compatible.  You can achieve a similar effect using \rightskip, but only over entire items.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292780/a-list-and-a-figure-side-by-side/292794?s=3|0.0612#292794 for example.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution -- instead of making one \minipage it's better to divide the list and the illustrations into two minipages. Then all of the following enumerated lists take up the whole page, looking just like they should! Relevant section of the code below:

```
\section{Толкование-Meaning}
{\large \textbf{Meanings:}}
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
    \item Культивируемое вечнозеленое растение, высушенные и особо обработанные листья которого при заварке дают ароматный тонизирующий напиток. \textit{Плантации чая. Сбор чая.} 
    \item Высушенные, измельченные и специально обработанные листья такого растения. \textit{Китайский, индийский, грузинский, русский ч. Байховый (рассыпной) и прессованный ч. Черный, зеленый ч. Заварить ч.}
    \item Напиток, настоянный на таких листьях. \textit{Крепкий, жидкий ч. Стакан чаю. Пригласить на чашку чая (в гости). Ч. пить - не дрова рубить (поcл.).}
    \item Настой из заваренных сушеных листьев или плодов какого-н. растения, ягод. \textit{Липовый ч. (настой на цветках липы). Малиновый ч. (настой на сушеной малине). Морковный ч. Брусничный ч.}
    \item То же, что чаепитие. \textit{Вечерний ч. За чаем. Позвать к чаю.}
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
\vspace{-110pt}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Camellia-sinensis-520x390.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{чай [1]}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{leaves.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{чай [2]}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
```