# Wrapfig does not work with esami after removing minipages for questions

Tags: wrapfigure, esami

I am writing exams using the esami package. Normally, it puts every mcq (multiple choice question) inside a minipage. When the question has a figure and I use wrapfig, everything works as expected, the figure is surrounded by text. BUT, when I use the new esami configuration where the minipages are removed (this in order to use the page space more efficiently) then wrapfig does not work.

I have already contacted the authors of esami and after their help we cleaned the MWE but were not able to solve the issues, so I am turning to post the question here in case anyone with package design experience could shed some light onto this issue.

In the following I will put the MWE for the quizz and the questions. The esami configuration is on the official url [esami configuration file](http://ctan.uniminuto.edu/macros/latex/contrib/esami/esami-xyz.cfg). In order to have the no-boxes version, you will need to uncomment the last part of that configuration file where it reads "%%%% %%%%% HERE I GET RID OF THE MINIPAGE IN MULTI"

- Basic question example with wrapfig put before the item (putting after item generates more problems):

  `\newproblem{
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (-1, 0) -- (5.1, 0);
    \draw [fill, red] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1];
    \draw [fill, red] (1.5, 0) circle [radius=0.1];
    \draw [fill, red] (4.5, 0) circle [radius=0.1];
    \node [below] at (0,-0.1) {1};
    \node [below] at (1.5,-0.1) {2};
    \node [below] at (4.5,-0.1) {3};
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{wrapfigure}
  \item \PTs{1.0}  question-v1 \blindtext[2]
    \begin{answers}{3}\bChoices[random]
  \Ans1 1. \eAns
  \Ans0 1. \eAns
  \eChoices
    \end{answers}
  }`
- Example question with wrapfig after the item: quizz using boxes (old version)

  `\newproblem{
  \item \PTs{1.0} question-v2 \blindtext[2]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick] (-1, 0) -- (5.1, 0);
        \draw [fill, red] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1];
        \draw [fill, red] (1.5, 0) circle [radius=0.1];
        \draw [fill, red] (4.5, 0) circle [radius=0.1];
        \node [below] at (0,-0.1) {1};
        \node [below] at (1.5,-0.1) {2};
        \node [below] at (4.5,-0.1) {3};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \blindtext[1]
    \begin{answers}{3}\bChoices[random]
      \Ans1 1. \eAns
      \Ans0 1. \eAns
      \eChoices
    \end{answers}
  }`
- example quizz using the normal configuration (boxes):

  `\documentclass[UKenglish,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[shuffle,xyz,pointsonright,autopston,nosolutions]{esami}%%%%% TEMA
  \usepackage{tikz} % 
  \usepackage{blindtext}
  \usepackage{wrapfig} % also for pgfmathparse
  \def\numcompiti{1}%%% The number of versions
  \date{2013/3/22}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT AAAA/M/D
  \def\Data{\longdate}%%% or \shortdate: the date in the heading
  \begin{document}
  \whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers
    \begin{test}[8]
  \begin{questions}
    \esercizi{question-v1, question-v2}
  \end{questions}
    \end{test}
  }
  \end{document}`
- example quizz using no - boxes (uncomment the section described above and save the file as xyz-n-boxes) - (this also even eliminates one question!!!):

  `\documentclass[UKenglish,a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage[shuffle,xyz-no-boxes,pointsonright,autopston,nosolutions]{esami}%%%%% TEMA
  \usepackage{tikz} % 
  \usepackage{blindtext}
  \usepackage{wrapfig} % also for pgfmathparse
  \def\numcompiti{1}%%% The number of versions
  \date{2013/3/22}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT AAAA/M/D
  \def\Data{\longdate}%%% or \shortdate: the date in the heading
  \begin{document}
  \whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers
    \begin{test}[8]
  \begin{questions}
    \esercizi{question-v1, question-v2}
  \end{questions}
    \end{test}
  }
  \end{document}`

Finally, if you want to see the results I obtain they are at [pdf results](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bwf1X0k7hGEiYXBiQWRkY2Vjb00?usp=sharing)

So, finally, if you have any idea on how to solve the problem with no boxes (without boxes the space is used better), you are welcome to say it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't try your code, I don't have the time to assemble all this snippets to something that can be compiled, but \item suggest a list, and wrapfig doesn't work good inside lists.

Comment: wrapfig package document is explicit that you can not use wrapfig within a latex list, that is any construct using `\item` so your document is not supported by the package

Comment: Hi, I am aware of that but wrapfig IS working inside the hidden list environment but fails when the configuration file removes the minipage (maybe there it becomes a list ...). In any case, to easy the testing, the google drive link includes all the files.

Comment: The amazing thing is not that is doesn't work with lists, but that it does work with minipages.  I bet they use \linewidth instead of \textwidth.  Anyway, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292780/a-list-and-a-figure-side-by-side.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that is the issue, altough without solution.