# Text wrapping on the right of pages

Tags: itemize, wrapfigure

How can we have pictures all to the right side of a page and text written to the left side? In my article, I have several pictures that we need to put to the right of every "item" in the "itemize" environment? I was trying to use the "wrapfigure" environment but it was working only for the first image but not for the second images it didn't where I needed it to be on the right of the text in the second "item" and so on

Comment: `wrapfig` and `itemize` don't work well together.

Comment: Please add an example to show what you tried so far. Probably, a sketch of the desired output could be helpful as well.

Comment: Please add [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example) for better understanding.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292780/a-list-and-a-figure-side-by-side