# Wrapping questions around figures

Tags: spacing, graphics, teaching

I am fairly new to this all. I'm a physics teacher, and simply trying to make some nice-looking question sheets for my students.

I am currently struggling to get pictures to sit NEXT to the text. I know there are minipage commands out there, but I was just wondering if there is anything ta little bit easier?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, oneside, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{geometry, rotating, sidecap}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={180mm,267mm},
 left=10mm,
 top=15mm,
 }

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\large\bf{Car Stopping Distances}}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The UK {\emph {Highway Code}} has a table of "Typical Stopping Distances" on straight roads in dry conditions. The diagram is based on this information.
                                %\begin{wrapfigure}{h}{0.3\textwidth}
                                %\centering
                                %\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{highwaycode}
                                %\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{highwaycode}}
\end{figure}
\\The shaded arrows represent the "thinking distance", the unshaded part the "braking distance", and the whole arrow the "stopping distance".
\begin{enumerate}
\item Make a table of the thinking distances d$_{think}$ and sketch a graph of d$_{think}$ against speed v, from v = 0 to v = 70 mph
\item Deduce a relation between these two variables
\item Predict the thinking distance for a police car travelling at 90 mph
\item How would the driver's consumption of alcohol/illegal substances affect the stopping distances? Explain your answer
\end{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item Using the {\emph {Highway Code}} data from the previous question, make a table of the braking distances d$_{brake}$ and sketch a graph of d$_{brake}$ against v, from v = 0 to v = 70 mph.
\item The relationship here is that d$_{brake}$ = $k$v$^{2}$, where $k$ is a constant. Test this statement by calculating $k$ for three numerical values of d$_{brake}$ and v.
\item Use the data to calculate the acceleration when braking from {\bf(i)} 50 mph, {\bf(ii)} 70 mph
\end{enumerate}
\item In France the motorways have different speed limits depending on the road condition.
They are:
\begin{itemize}
\item when dry 130 kmh$^{-1}$
\item when wet 110 kmh$^{-1}$
\end{itemize}
Using the $\frac{5}{8}$ ratio, translate these into mph, and comment on the French system.\\
%   \begin{minipage}[]{0.55\linewidth}
\item A person who is properly held by a seat belt has a good chance of surviving a car collision if the deceleration does not exceed 30g. Assuming uniform deceleration at this rate, calculate the distance that the front section of the car must crumple if a crash occurs at 65 kmh$^{-1}$ 
                                %\begin{wrapfigure}{h}{0.6\textwidth}
                                %\centering
                                %\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{crumple}
                                %\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{crumple}}
\end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Any advice would be most appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292780/a-list-and-a-figure-side-by-side

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnKormylo!

Comment: So should we mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I hsve still not managed to make it work! Probably doing something really stupid..

Comment: How about wrapfigure environment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846233/wrapping-text-around-a-figure-in-latex#2847343

Answer (score 1):

This solution creates environment `textbox` (awful name) which takes an image as its argument (or a `\parbox` or `minipage` if needed).  It differs from wrapfigure in that it **will** work with lists, but will not shape paragraphs.  Since each `\item` is a separate paragraph, that should not be a problem.

Just keep all your environments properly nested.  You can use the `[resume*]` feature of the enumitem package to add more items outside `textbox`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, oneside, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{geometry, rotating, sidecap}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={180mm,267mm},
 left=10mm,
 top=15mm,
 }

\newsavebox{\tempbox}% reserve global name

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{textbox}[1]% #1 = image (possibley parbox or minipage with \caption)
{\savebox\tempbox{\def\@captype{figure}#1}% measure image (also preserve for \endtextbox)
  \minipage[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\columnsep-\wd\tempbox}}%
{\endminipage\hfill\raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\ht\tempbox}{\usebox\tempbox}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\large\bf{Car Stopping Distances}}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The UK {\emph {Highway Code}} has a table of "Typical Stopping Distances" on straight roads in dry conditions. The diagram is based on this information.

\begin{textbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
The shaded arrows represent the "thinking distance", the unshaded part the "braking distance", and the whole arrow the "stopping distance".
\begin{enumerate}% second layer
\item Make a table of the thinking distances d$_{think}$ and sketch a graph of d$_{think}$ against speed v, from v = 0 to v = 70 mph
\item Deduce a relation between these two variables
\item Predict the thinking distance for a police car travelling at 90 mph
\item How would the driver's consumption of alcohol/illegal substances affect the stopping distances? Explain your answer
\end{enumerate}
\end{textbox}

\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item Using the {\emph {Highway Code}} data from the previous question, make a table of the braking distances d$_{brake}$ and sketch a graph of d$_{brake}$ against v, from v = 0 to v = 70 mph.
\item The relationship here is that d$_{brake}$ = $k$v$^{2}$, where $k$ is a constant. Test this statement by calculating $k$ for three numerical values of d$_{brake}$ and v.
\item Use the data to calculate the acceleration when braking from {\bf(i)} 50 mph, {\bf(ii)} 70 mph
\end{enumerate}
\item In France the motorways have different speed limits depending on the road condition.
They are:
\begin{itemize}
\item when dry 130 kmh$^{-1}$
\item when wet 110 kmh$^{-1}$
\end{itemize}
Using the $\frac{5}{8}$ ratio, translate these into mph, and comment on the French system.\\

\begin{textbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
\item A person who is properly held by a seat belt has a good chance of surviving a car collision if the deceleration does not exceed 30g. Assuming uniform deceleration at this rate, calculate the distance that the front section of the car must crumple if a crash occurs at 65 kmh$^{-1}$
\end{textbox}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```